# C++ Trying to shift number right by 32 gives two different results

Tags: c++, bit-shift

I was writing a small program to get some experience with bit manipulation and I encountered this situation. I was trying to create a mask that sets 0`s all the bits from MSB to some number n. The problem arises when my n is 32. Here is some code that demonstrates the problem.

```
int n = (sizeof(int) * 8) - 0; //Here n is basically set to 32.
    std::cout << n << std::endl; //And indeed, this prints 32.

    //here I expect to see 0 (basically all 32 bits of the number should be 0`s, but I see the opposite, all bits are set to 1.)
    std::cout << ((unsigned) ~0 >> n) << std::endl;

    //And this indeed does what I expected and all 32 bits of the nuber are set to 0`s.
    std::cout << ((unsigned) ~0 >> 32) << std::endl;
```

my question is, since n = 32, why am I seeing 2 different results here wherein 1st one I am seeing 32 `s and in the 2nd case, I am seeing 32 0`s?

Comment: Shifting a 32-bit value by 32 (or more) bits is undefined behavior.

Comment: Ok, that will explain the situation that I am facing. Could you please provide more info as to why it is undefined?

Comment: Only shifting 32-bit signed integers by 32 results in undefined behavior. Unsigned integers are fine with this. It's all about shifting sign bit.

Comment: It is undefined behaviour because the C Standard (and the C++ Standard, and the Objective-C Standard) say so. That's it. It's also undefined behaviour because some processors have instructions that will ignore all but the lowest 5 bits of a variable shift amount. In this case, the effect of undefined behaviour is that a shift by a constant 32 and a variable 32 gives different results.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Apparently this is wrong and the original poster tested it(thanks!). I'll leave it up as an idea if someone has a better explanation.

---

I think you didn't think about what your types are being casted to.
You're probably executing this on a 64 bit machine, therefore n is a 32 bit unsigned integer but the number 32 is a 64 bit long integer.

`~0`  becomes an unsigned int (32 bit)

`n` is a 32 bit unsigned integer

`32` is (probably) a 64 bit long

combining `~0`(32 bit) and `n`(32 bit) probably gives an answer on 32 bit

whereas combining `~0`(32 bit) and `32`(64 bit) gives an answer on 64 bit

As stated in the comments to your question, shifting a number by all it's bits is an undefined behavior, **but shifting them in a 64 bit integer by 32 bit should work!**

This is my best guess, I didn't test this out.

Comment: Hmm, casting 32 to an int and checking the result gave me the same non-consistent answer. I don't think that is the reason here.

Comment: Wow, thanks for testing it. This was my guess, but then I'm wondering why you're getting such behavior(maybe compiler optimization that changes the something?)

Comment: Now that is a good idea. I will have to test it without the optimizer to see what I get. I will do that and post back with the result.